# When focus and editing TextInput it breaks value at left

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a TextInput with maxLength 5, but when editing the first char is "cut". I already tried paddingLeft but doesn't makes any difference.

This happens with both iOS and android.

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epi9i.png)

My component:

```
<TextInput
  // onChangeText={value => changeInput()} - this will be field in the future
  defaultValue='00,00'
  style={style.value}
  autoCapitalize="none"
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  keyboardType="number-pad"
  maxLength={5}
/>
```

Style:

```
  value: {
    color: color.white,
    fontFamily: FontRegular,
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
  },
```

Comment: TextInput is a controlled component, you need to use onChangeText to update the value

Answer (score 0):

The problem was totally a style question, not about the functionality of the input. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.

I solved adding a fixed width.